# Copy and paste issue with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim, vi

When I copy a text from a browser and paste it into a file I opened using `vi` in Terminal, I get the following unformatted text. Why does vi or the Terminal ignoring the newlines?

**Instead of getting the following:**

```
" Restore cursor position to where it was before
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
   au!
   autocmd BufReadPost *
            \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
            \   if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
            \     let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
            \     let b:doopenfold = 1 |
            \     if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
            \        let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = JumpCursorO
```

**I get this:**

```
" Restore cursor position to where it was before
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
   au!
      autocmd BufReadPost *
                  \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
                              \   if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
                                          \     let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
                                                      \     let b:doopenfold = 1 |
                                                                  \     if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
```

Comment: @Matt: No. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504

Comment: @sidyll I stand corrected. Thank you `:)`

Answer (score 4):

This is the fault of vi, not Mac OS X or Terminal.  Vi isn't ignoring the newlines; it's just accumulating indentation.  You can fix this by turning autoindent off (`:set noai`) before pasting and turning it back on afterwards, or, if you're using Vim (which I believe vi is just a symlink to in Mac OS X) you can temporarily turn the `paste` option on, which disables autoindent along with several other features that can cause problems when pasting text.

Comment: Espouse using `paste` option.  See also `pastetoggle`.

Answer (score 4):

Even better than `:set paste` is to just us the mac clipboard.

If you're using vim 7.3, you can add this to your `~/.vimrc` file to get yank (`y`) and paste (`p`) to use the Mac`s cut and paste buffer:

```
if has("macunix")
  if v:version >= 703
    " Default yank and paste go to Mac's clipboard
    set clipboard=unnamed
  endif
endif
```

You can safely put it in your `.vimrc` even if you don't have Vim 7.3 -- it just won't work.

You can get the latest vim using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and the [homebrew-alt](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt) repositories.  I recommend it!

Comment: I think this is better, although I prefer using the system keyboard (`"*p`) rather than overriding the default one. If you don't want to install an updated version of vim, the [fakeclip plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098) will also work.